# Lua match, поиск символа после пробела

Tags: lua, match

> В заданной последовательности чисел подсчитать количество пар
>   (последовательно расположенных чисел), представленных положительными
>   значениями, и количество пар, значения элементов которых имеют
>   противоположный знак. Вывести сообщение о том, количество которых пар
>   преобладает.

```
local function main()
print("Введите строку")
p = 0
m = 0
str = io.read()
a = string.len(str)
for i = 1, a do
  if str:sub(i,i) == "+" and str:sub(i+3,i+3) == "+" then
    p=p+1
  else if str:sub(i,i)== "-"  and str:sub(i+3,i+3) == "-" then
     m = m+1
      end
       end
end
  if p > m then
    print("Положительная последовательность больше")
  else if m > p then
    print("Отрицательная последовательность больше")
  else 
    print("Последовательности равны") 
     end 
      end
        end

main()
```

в такой последовательности +3 +4 -5 -5 -5 я сравниваю первый символ с третьим и так далее. но проблема в том что может быть двухзначное число и тогда программа сработает не корректно, как можно обойти эту проблему. мне match  может помочь? ну что бы искать пробел и сравнить со знаком после него? или  как-то по другому можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переписал код из ответа выше, но на шаблонах. Вот что получилось:

```
local function get_counts(str)  
  local plus, minus = 0, 0  
  local last_sign = nil

  for sign, digit in str:gmatch("([+-])(%d+)") do    
    print(sign .. digit) -- печатает найденные знак и число
    if sign == last_sign then -- нашли пару
      if sign == "+" then 
        plus = plus + 1 
      else
        minus = minus + 1
      end            
    else
      last_sign = sign  
    end    
  end      
  return plus, minus
end

local function main()    
  local positive_count, negative_count = get_counts("+3 +4 -5 -55 -5 -200 +10")

  print("Положительных пар: " .. positive_count)
  print("Отрицательных пар: " .. negative_count)

  if positive_count > negative_count then
    print("Положительная последовательность больше")
  elseif negative_count > positive_count then
    print("Отрицательная последовательность больше")
  else 
    print("Последовательности равны") 
  end 
end

main()
```

Вот что функция напечатает:

```
+3
+4
-5
-55
-5
-200
+10
Положительных пар: 1
Отрицательных пар: 3
Отрицательная последовательность больше
```

Ключевым моментом этой функции является строка:

```
for sign, digit in str:gmatch("([+-])(%d+)") do
```

тут создаётся итератор по заданной строке `str`, с шаблоном `([+-])(%d+)`. Этот итератор для каждого совпадения возвращает нам отдельно знак числа в `sign` и само число в `digit`.

Comment: да так было задумано -5 -55 -5 это последовательность из двух пар -5 -55 и -55 -5

Comment: @P.L ок, исправил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Переписал ваш код. Основная логика подсчета пар выполняется в функции `getPositiveNegativePairsCount`. Ввод исходных данных вы так же можете ожидать со стандартного входного потока, как и было ранее.

В коде производится очень простой анализ строки: пробегаем по всем символам и при встрече знаков `+` или `-` выставляем `last_symbol`. При следующем встрече одного из двух символов либо взводим счетчик пары, либо переключаем `last_symbol` на другой знак

```
SIGN = { PLUS="+", MINUS="-" }

local function getPositiveNegativePairsCount(inputStr)
  local result = {}
  for key, val in pairs(SIGN) do
    result[val] = 0
  end

  local last_symbol = nil

  local length = string.len(inputStr)
  print("length = ", length)

  for idx = 1, length do
    local symbol = string.sub(inputStr, idx, idx)

    if result[symbol] then
      if symbol == last_symbol then
        result[symbol] = result[symbol] + 1
      else
        last_symbol = symbol
      end
    end
  end

  return result[SIGN.PLUS], result[SIGN.MINUS]
end

local function main()

  local positive_count, negative_count = getPositiveNegativePairsCount("+3 +4 -5 -55 -5")
  print("positive pairs count = ", positive_count)
  print("negative pairs count = ", negative_count)

  if positive_count > negative_count then
    print("Положительная последовательность больше")
  elseif negative_count > positive_count then
    print("Отрицательная последовательность больше")
  else 
    print("Последовательности равны") 
  end 
end

main()
```

PS Похоже в `lua` нельзя получить символ по индексу используя оператор [], `local symbol = inputStr[idx]` возвращает `nil`. По этой причине использую вызов `local symbol = string.sub(inputStr, idx, idx)`